# How to run sidekiq in background using dockerfile

Tags: sidekiq

How to run sidekiq and rails  in separate container using Dockerfile. In local i am using docker compose to build containers as it creates 3 separate containers each for app,sidekiq and redis but when i deploy application which uses Dockerfile where sidekiq and rails running in same container and sidekiq is running in foreground and processing jobs. How to make sidekiq run in background?

Sidekiq version - 6.3.1 | Rails version - 6.0.3 | Ruby - 2.7

---

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ruby:2.7

RUN mkdir -p /src

ENV RAILS_ENV="development"

COPY Gemfile* /src/

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y unzip && \
.
.
.
.
.

RUN bundle install

RUN mkdir tmp

RUN chmod +x bin/docker-entrypoint.sh

CMD bin/docker-entrypoint.sh
```

---

bin/docker-entrypoint.sh :

```bash
#!/bin/bash
set -e

rake db:create

rake db:migrate

bundle exec sidekiq -e "${RAILS_ENV}" -C config/sidekiq.yml & bundle exec rails s
```

Answer (score 1):

The best approach is to run Sidekiq in a different container than the Rails process. You can use the same Dockerfile and just change the entrypoint, for instance:

```
if [ "$1" = "sidekiq" ]; then
  bundle exec sidekiq
else
  exec "$@"
fi
```

This way it's easy to run locally, with or without compose, and it's ready to deploy, just pass the flag to the entrypoint and you are good to go.

Comment: Thank you for your reply but using above script it will starts only sidekiq, it wont start rails server. How to run rails and sidekiq in 2 different containers by making sidekiq run in background?

Comment: Hey, so if you running this locally go with a docker-compose file. You can just copy the build from the rails server and specify the entrypoint, for example

sidekiq:
  build: *rails-server
  entrypoint: entrypoint.sh sidekiq
  env: 
     - REDIS_URL: ....

For deployment it really depends on how you are deploying it.